# Changing the structure of the data?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a chat application. I am in the progress of creating a group chat and as a current user who wants to create a group chat, I have added the current user in the group list.

I am using Realtime database. I managed to select which contacts to add into the group list and finally, create a group. However, I got error when I click "Create Group" which is after I selected the members I want to add. The error I got is

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'ConnectionModel' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'ConnectionModel'
Tried calling: []("uid"))
```

I can understand that is because of the way my data is structured but I couldn't fix it.

```
[{uid: zO58VZG9wUT9kKxSZrduDVS2IHe2, isAdmin: true, email: jeleven295@gmail.com, status: Unavailable, type: trainers, password: L8l9sf89@},  123@test.com, 123 Test, clients, cJB2l7dqx9g7JddiRjqGNDXIXk03,  123@test.com, 123 Test, clients, cJB2l7dqx9g7JddiRjqGNDXIXk03]
```

As you can see, the first user is current user. The second and third user is 123 Test. It does not have the same structure. I was wondering if that affects the process of creating a group chat because the data structure is different.

I retrieve my current user and add to list with this code

```
  getCurrentUserDetails() async {
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref()
    .child('users')
    .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .onValue
    .listen((event) {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = event.snapshot.value as Map;
  setState(() {
    groupList.add({
      "uid": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      "isAdmin": true,
      "email": map['email'],
      "status": map['status'],
      "type": map['type'],
      "password": map['password'],
    });
    print(groupList);
  });
});
```

}

Then I retrieve my connections list that I want to add into my group list. I do it by creating a DatabaseService.dart.

```
class DatabaseService {


 static Future<List<ConnectionModel>> getConnections() async {

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('chats');

Query query = ref.orderByKey();
DataSnapshot event = await query.get();

final database = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref()
    .child('connections')
    .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .once();

List<ConnectionModel> connections = [];
Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshot = database.snapshot.children;

for (var element in dataSnapshot) {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = element.value as Map;

  connections.add(ConnectionModel.fromJson(values));
  print(connections);

  // print(values);
}
return connections;
  }
}
```

Then I call it in my creategroup.dart so that I can show the connections I have that I want to add into my grouplist.

```
  _setupNeeds() async {
    List<ConnectionModel> needs = await DatabaseService.getConnections();
    setState(() {
      connectionList = needs;
      print(connectionList);
    });
  }
```

After I select the connections(friends), I will be directed to give a group chat name. This is how I create the group chat.

```
 void createGroup() async {
setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
});

String groupId = const Uuid().v1();

ref.child('groups').child(_auth.currentUser!.uid).child(groupId).set({
  "group_members": widget.groupList,
  "group_id": groupId,
  "group_name": _groupName.text,
});

for (int i = 0; i < widget.groupList.length; i++) {
  String uid = widget.groupList[i]['uid'];
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref()
      .child('users')
      .child(uid)
      .child('groups')
      .push();

  ref.set({
    "name": _groupName.text,
    "id": groupId,
  });
}

final sendChat = ref.child('group_chats').child(groupId).push();
sendChat.set({
  "groupchatid": groupId,
  "message": "${_auth.currentUser!.uid} Created This Group.",
  "message_status": "delivered",
  "sendby": _auth.currentUser!.uid,
  "sendto": _groupName.text,
  "time": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
  "type": "notify",
});

if (!mounted) return;
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const TrainerBottomNavBar()),
    (route) => false);
```

}

On this line,   `String uid = widget.groupList[i]['uid'];` is where I get the error which is `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'ConnectionModel' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of 'ConnectionModel' Tried calling: []("uid"))`

Comment: Can you include sample snippet, the way you are trying to fetch it

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Apologies for my mistake. I updated. Hope it clears up my question...